# using LARGE_INTEGER gives me back error error C2679: '=' binary no operator found which takes a right-hand operand

Tags: c++

i have the following code:

```
QueryPerformanceCounter(&timeStart);
winMain::render(); //do stuff
QueryPerformanceCounter(&timeEnd);
numCounts = ( timeEnd.QuadPart - timeStart.QuadPart);
```

All the 3 variables are declared as LARGE_INTEGER, the code should work since im following a book example, but i get:

error C2679: '='  binary no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type LONGLONG
it might be '_LARGE_INTEGER &_LARGE_INTEGER::operator =(const _LARGE_INTEGER &)'
1>        durante la ricerca di corrispondenza con l'elenco di argomenti '(LARGE_INTEGER, LONGLONG)'

Comment: Are you sure you are not trying to subtract LARGE_INTEGER from LARGE_INTEGER or something else? Subtracting the quadpart should be fine as they are just long long data type.

Comment: i dont think so, im following the book and that's all the code i have, apart from the declaration of the 3 variables as LARGE_INTEGER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to assign a LONGLONG to a LARGE_INTEGER. No such assignment exists. Perhaps you meant to assign to numCounts.QuadPart.

Comment: ok i guess this was the problem! changing it to numCounts.QuadPart = ( timeEnd.QuadPart - timeStart.QuadPart); solved the problem. So the book was wrong..thanks! :)